# Angularjs validate

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I want validate my form using ajax , but the errors are not showing properly. 
Here is my code:

Html

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="dkController">
<form ng-submit="dk()">
<label>Username</label>
<input type="text" name="username" ng-model="formdata.user">
{{errorName}}
<label>Password</label>
<input type="text" name="password" ng-model="formdata.pass">
<label>Email</label>
<input type="text" name="email" ng-model="formdata.email">
<button type="submit" >Submit</button>
{{message}}

</form>
</body>
```

Js

```
function dkController($http,$scope){
                $scope.formdata={};
                $scope.dk = function(){
                    $http({
                        method:"POST",
                        url:"dk.php",
                        data:$.param($scope.formdata)
                    })
                    .then(function(response){
                        $scope.errorName = response.data.errors.username;
                    })
```

and PHP

```
$conn= new mysqli('localhost','root','','dangky');
$username   = isset($_POST['username']) ? trim($_POST['username']) : '';
$sql="SELECT *FROM dangky where username='$username'";
$result= mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

$errors=array();
$data=array();
if(empty($username))
$errors['username']='user name is required';

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    if ($row['username'] == $username){
        $errors['check'] = 'Tên đăng nhập đã tồn tại';
}
}
if(!empty($errors)){
    $data['success']=false;
    $data['errors']=$errors;
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Error username is showing but errors check not showing .

This is the php output

```
{"success":false,"errors":{"username":"user name is required"}} .
```

Comment: read these links before posting again.
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Answer (score 0):

The problem is youu passed $scope.formdata which contains

```
{ user : 'someone', pass: 'abc123!', email: 'me@medotcom' }
```

Your PHP script is looking for post data `{ username: 'someone' }`

So rename your ng-model to `ng-model="formdata.username"` or change your PHP to find `$_POST['user']`. Your choice but they must match.